# The periodic timer is duplicated in initState ()

Tags: flutter

When switching to another page, a periodic timer is started in initState (). But it is duplicated.

Or I am making a wrong transition to another page. Or initState () is doubled.

Code for moving from one page to another:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => new MapPage(phone: _phone)));
```

Timer call:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timerSendPointStart = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        makePoint();
      });
    });
  }
```

Can you please tell me where the error is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

use `onWillPop()` life cycle hook to stop the timer/delete the timer before navigating to another screen. otherwise, you will get the timer's overflow.

It's also good to cancel the timer in the `dispose()` function.

Comment: Can you see my code and comment on timers? Perhaps I have a problem with the structure of the code.

First page:
https://github.com/Lightunit/flutter_mobile_new/blob/main/lib/main.dart

The second page starts the timers (_timer and _timerSendPointStart):
https://github.com/Lightunit/flutter_mobile_new/blob/main/lib/mappage.dart